# How to trigger callbacks jquery 3.1.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I like is the best way to handle my `.fail()` & `.done()` when my ajax request returns with a assoc array that I parse.

This is my current code and my current problem is `.fail()`.  always firing.

**Note:** I tested my `something.php` and its giving me the right response when it fail or when it succeeded this is the actual response to my `something.php`

Fail :

```
{
  "ac":"failed"
}
```

Success :

```
{
  "alias": "cd9d0e2e",
  "sso": "http://somethin.com/home/site/cd9d0e2e?dm_sso=2!dsa654654sa56d FGfre4f645465fTIxYWE3NGZkMzk0NGM3NzIyMWFhNWQyMTgifQ",
  "ru": "http://somethin.com/login/resetpwd?uuid=asd1as3d1as321d-4370-be5d-123a3s2d1a3sd13a2s",
  "ac": "something@sample.com",
  "fn": "Fish",
  "ln": "Fillet"
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-create').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var cSite = createSite();
       cSite.done(sendMail).fail(failOption).always(alwaysOption);
    }
});

function createSite() {
     var promise = $.Deferred();
     $.ajax({
             url: 'something.php',
             method: 'POST',
         data:"template_id="+template_id+"&original_url="+original_url+"&email="+email+"&first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name
            }).then(function(data) {
                var dataa = JSON.parse(data);
                //debugger;
                if(dataa.ac === 'failed') {
                    promise.reject(dataa);
                } else {
                    promise.resolve(dataa);
                }
            });

            return promise;
        }
function sendMail(dataa) {
console.log(dataa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the `promise` form your `createSite` function.

`var cSite = createSite();` and then use with `.then`, `.done`, .always or `.fail` etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-create').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cSite = createSite();
    cSite.done(function(resp) {
      var dataa = JSON.parse(resp);
      sendMail(dataa);
    }).fail(failOption).always(alwaysOption);
  });
});

function createSite() {
  var promise = $.ajax({
    url: 'something.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: "template_id=" + template_id + "&original_url=" + original_url + "&email=" + email + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&last_name=" + last_name
  })
  return promise;
}

function sendMail(dataa) {
  console.log(dataa);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but what  I want is to execute `.done()`  when only if i have this data 

{
  "alias": "cd9d0e2e",
  "sso": "http://somethin.com/home/site/cd9d0e2e?dm_sso=2!dsa654654sa56d FGfre4f645465fTIxYWE3NGZkMzk0NGM3NzIyMWFhNWQyMTgifQ",
  "ru": "http://somethin.com/login/resetpwd?uuid=asd1as3d1as321d-4370-be5d-123a3s2d1a3sd13a2s",
  "ac": "something@sample.com",
  "fn": "Fish",
  "ln": "Fillet"
}

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figure it out now .. this is the code that works now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-create').click(function(e){
            //debugger; 
            e.preventDefault();
                $(this).html('Creating Site');
                var template_id = $("#template_id").val();
                var original_url = $("#original_url").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
                var last_name = $("#last_name").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'create-site-con.2.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data:"template_id="+template_id+"&original_url="+original_url+"&email="+email+"&first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name
                    }).done(function(resp) {
                        var dataa = JSON.parse(resp);
                             if (dataa.ac === "failed"){
                                failOption(dataa);
                              }
                             else{
                                 sendMail(dataa);
                              }
                    });

            });//click
            });//doc ready
```